# Java scanner. Why do I get could not find file when running this?

Tags: java

Java scanner. Why do I get  could not find file when running this? Am i doing something wrong. I know the file exists in the directory and there are a few lines of text in it. Its a file with no extension but even when I add a file with an extension it still does not run.

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package brownK_OSpgm2.java;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author kirkt
 */

public class brownK_OSpgm2 {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */    
    private Scanner x;       
    public void openFile() {

        try
        {                  
            x = new Scanner(new File("RAMerrors8x4"));     
        }

        catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("Could not find file darn it");
        }
    }

    public void readFile()
    {

    while(x.hasNext()){

    String a = x.next();
    String b = x.next();
    String c = x.next();


    System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", a,b,c);

    }
    }

    public void closeFile() {

    x.close();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println ("Hello World");

    brownK_OSpgm2 r = new brownK_OSpgm2();

    r.openFile();
    r.readFile();
    r.closeFile();

}      

}
```

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to print the `Exception` details. Might be something else that's wrong and you just assume that the file was not found. Also, what directory are you reading from? Try to see if the file is present in `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))` folder.

Comment: Try printing out `new File("RAMerrors8x4").getAbsolutePath()`, that will give you the exact **absolute** path you are using. You will be able to exclude any issues related to relative paths resolution.